Nutanix "dstNumTotalBytes" MIB OID not working in Datadog integration
This issue about SNMP MIB mapping and integration with Datadog. The problem is I'm not getting any data for the dstNumTotalBytes in Datadog metrics explorer. Values I'm getting when I did with SNMP walk.
The MIB for the dstNumTotalBytes is 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.6
NUTANIX_MIB
https://mibbrowser.online/mibdb_search.php?mib=NUTANIX-MIB
Datadog Metrics Explorer View:
enter image description here
I tried to get disk total value in different MIB like this but it's also not working:
        - MIB: NUTANIX-MIB
          symbol:
            - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.6
              name: ntxdstNumTotalBytes

This is my current MIB mapping and not working ntxdstNumRawBytes:
sysobjectid:
  - 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263

# diskInformation
metrics:

  - MIB: NUTANIX-MIB
    table:
      OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1
      name: ntxDiskStatusTable
      matric_type: gauge
    symbols:
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.13
        name: ntxdstState
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.5
        name: ntxdstNumRawBytes
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.7
        name: ntxdstNumFreeBytes
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.6
        name: ntxdstNumTotalBytes
        matric_type: gauge
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.8
        name: ntxdstNumTotalInodes
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.10
        name: ntxdstAverageLatency
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.11
        name: ntxdstIOBandwidth
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.12
        name: ntxdstNumberIops
    metric_tags:
      - column:
          OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.1
          name: ntxdstDiskId
        tag: ntx_disk_index

# storagePoolInformation
  - MIB: NUTANIX-MIB
    table:
      OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7
      name: ntxstoragePoolInformationTable
    symbols:
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7.1.4
        name: ntxspitTotalCapacity
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7.1.5
        name: ntxspitUsedCapacity
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7.1.6
        name: ntxspitIOPerSecond
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7.1.7
        name: ntxspitAvgLatencyUsecs
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7.1.8
        name: ntxspitIOBandwidth
    metric_tags:
      - column:
          OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.7.1.1
          name: ntxspitIndex
        tag: ntx_spit_index

# hypervisorInformation
  - MIB: NUTANIX-MIB
    table:
      OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9
      name: ntxhypervisorInformationTable
    symbols:
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.5
        name: ntxhypervisorCpuCount
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.6
        name: ntxhypervisorCpuUsagePercent
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.7
        name: ntxhypervisorMemory
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.8
        name: ntxhypervisorMemoryUsagePercent
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.9
        name: hypervisorReadIOPerSecond
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.10
        name: hypervisorWriteIOPerSecond
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.11
        name: hypervisorAverageLatency
      - OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.12
        name: hypervisorIOBandwidth
    metric_tags:
      - column:
          OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.9.1.1
          name: ntxhypervisorIndex
        tag: ntx_hyper_index


Update: I was able to get the total value after updating the mib format.
diskInformation
metrics:

MIB: NUTANIX-MIB
table:
OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1
name: ntxDiskStatusTable
symbols:
name: ntx.dstNumTotalBytes
matric_type: gauge
metric_tags:

tag: ntx_disk_index
column:
OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.1
name: ntxdstIndex
tage: ntx_disk_id
column:
OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.3.1.2
name: ntxdstDiskId



